# ReadStream With Lock (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, fs

`var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath)`
how to have **readStream** with **shared/exclusive lock**
so, that file can not be **deleted** or **altered**

Comment: https://github.com/baudehlo/node-fs-ext#fsflockfd-flags-callback

Comment: @robertklep is has python dependency, i wanted some pure js solution

Comment: The Python dependency is because these operations can only be implemented as a C++ addon, which requires Python for the build process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think node exposes any filesystem locking mechanisms.

If you were going to use filesystem for system-wide locks or secure inter-process communication, you'll need to find another way (e.g. sockets).

If it's not security critical there are some ways of making it harder (but not impossible) for other processes to mess with your files:

- Use unguessable filenames. `require('crypto').getRandomBytes('16').toString('hex')`
- Narrow permissions when creating files via options on `createReadStream`.
- Run node process as a special user, so files will be owned only by that user. Either configure OS to run node under appropriate user, or have node run as root and switch to another user via `process.setuid`/`setgid`.